# How to implement basic feature in C

Tags: c, cs50

This code will take the user input and use it to build blocks.
Entering a number between 1 and 8 it should print something like this.

```
###
###
###
```

I want it to take the integer from the user and instead print the blocks like this. Say the user enters the number 5. Currently you'll get this.

```
#####
#####
#####
#####
#####
```

However I want it to do this.

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

Can anyone help me understand how to implement this?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Size: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: the outer loop counts to 5 so the index counts 0,1,2,3,4 and you want to output 1,2,3,4,5 marks.  so the inner loop should count i+1 number of times yes? not n number of times, yes?  giving you 1,2,3,4,5 marks per outer loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)`

to `for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)`

The number of `#` will increase with each loop as `i` increases